# relation between stationary and independent increment

Tags: distribution-theory, renewal-processes

I am a little confused about the relation between stationary and independent increment. I think if a process does not have independent increment, it does have stationary increment either. Is that right.

Comment: Yeah, I am asking if a counting process does not have independent increment, does it have stationary increment?

Comment: Let {N(t)}, $t\geq 0$ denote a counting process. stationary increment means N($t_1 + s$) - N(($t_2 + s$)) has the same distribution as N($t_1$) - N(($t_2 $)) for any $t_2 <t_1$ and $s>0$

Answer (score 1):

For a general stochastic process, fractional brownian motion (with $H\neq 1/2$) would be a counterexample.  It doesn't have independent increments, but it does have stationary increments.

For a counting process, you can get a counterexample by letting $N(t) : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{N}$ denote a poisson process and then define $f(t) : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{N}$ by $$f(t) = \lfloor t\rfloor N(1) + N(\{t\})$$
It's easy to see this doesn't have independent increments (e.g. $f(2)-f(1) = f(1) - f(0)$), but it has stationary increments.